# .htaccess with .htpasswd always 500 internal server error

Tags: php, .htaccess, .htpasswd

My htaccess is giving some problems.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please Log In"
AuthUserFile ./lib/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Satisfy any
```

The ip whitelist works.
But the authentication doesnt work.
When i give some data to the login page it returns 500 internal server error

I tried lots of things and couldn't fix it

My htpasswd:

```
user:fv6WWK8ZYdGtU
```

Comment: First think you always should do with such errors: take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read what the actual issue is.

Comment: _I tried lots of things and couldn't fix it_ What have you tryied? DO you have any code to post?

Comment: http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/ use something like this to generate a password, I'm pretty sure you can't use plain text passwords like that

Comment: I cant access the error log. External hosting.

Comment: Try changing `AuthUserFile ./lib/.htpasswd` to `AuthUserFile /lib/.htpasswd`

Comment: I tried different formats, htpasswd generators. different file permissions, different AuthUserFile path's etc.

Comment: Provide full filesystem path to the password file. To discover your filesystem path, you can create a PHP document containing `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

Comment: I also used full system path without succes :(

Comment: By any chance are you using localhost such as wamp?

Comment: No it is an external hosting provider

Comment: Wesley where is your .htpasswd file located? is it in Root folder or outside the root?